# Azure Pipeline - Automating Android Version Code

Tags: android, azure, azure-devops

I picked up a project that had been managed by another team and the last released version use a  version code of 5034.

They had been pushing these out from a developers machine directly rather than using a formal build process.

In my build script I have a manifest versioning step defined as:

```
- task: android-manifest-version@1
  displayName: 'Set Android version numbers'
  inputs: 
    sourcePath: '$(androidManifestPath)'
    versionCodeOption: 'buildid'
    versionCode: $(Build.BuildId)
    versionName: $(baseVersion).$(Build.BuildId)
    printFile: true
```

But our buildId is at a much lower number (4444) at the moment.

Looking over the available variables [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), nothing seems to be jumping out as a solution.

I suppose I could just set this to a value manually in the build script but that feels a little dirty.

Is there a simple solution I'm overlooking?

**UPDATE**

I'm wondering if I could use something like this:

Create a new variable in my custom shared-variables.yml like:

versionCodePrefix: '600'

And then in the scripts use this

versionCode: $(versionCodePrefix)$(Rev:r)

**UPDATE2**

I've just found this option for the build step:

versionCodeOption: 'timestamp'

Inserts a unix format time stamp. Going to try this approach.

Comment: So your problem is that published versionCode is `5034` and you wana use `Build.BuildId` in next release ? ... you may multiply it by 10 ... (or create fake 590 builds to bump Build.BuildId over 5034 :D)

Comment: Kind of. The issue is that the built in BuildId is organisation wide and cannot be "bumped" as far as I can tell and none of the other build in variables seem to make sense.

Comment: I just updated the question with a potential solution.

Comment: Why not produce it, set it as an environmental variable, and then run the rest?Gradle can use the environmental variable, as long as you have set it before anything gradle related happens.

Comment: This isn't using Gradle, its a remote build pipeline process hosted within Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out the [versioning plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-473885.motz-mobile-buildtasks&ssr=false) has a few options I'd not investigated.

My final yml task looks like this:

```
task: android-manifest-version@1
  displayName: 'Set Android version numbers'
  inputs: 
    sourcePath: '$(androidManifestPath)'
    versionCodeOption: 'buildid'
    versionCode: $(Build.BuildId)
    versionCodeOffset: '1000'
    versionName: $(baseVersion).$(Build.BuildId)
    printFile: true
```

Keeping it all automated but by using the `versionCodeOffset` value it combines by adding the two integer values together. So a build version of `2.0.4448` will result in a `versionCode` of 5448.

Comment: What does $(Build.BuildId) refer to? what is the buildId is gotten from?